# Click and Hold OnMouseDown Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, onmousedown

I want my OnMouseDown command to work only when the player presses over an object within the game. At the moment, the player can press anywhere and the timer will start. Is there a way to have the timer only start when they click and hold an object? To give you some context, I want an object to become inactive when the player clicks and holds over it.

Here is my code so far:

```
function Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if ( Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        timer = 0;
    }
    if(timer > 1)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);    
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity 5: How can I detect a touch on a custom button and object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329959/unity-5-how-can-i-detect-a-touch-on-a-custom-button-and-object)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: 
I used a Raycast in order to do this:

```
var ray: Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
var hit : RaycastHit;   

 if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && coll.Raycast(ray,hit,100))
 {
 timer += Time.deltaTime;
 }
 if ( Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
 {
    timer = 0;
 }
```